# Сборка JavaFX проекта

Tags: java, javafx

Не удается никак собрать исполняемый жарник. Собираю проект как и через `project structure - artifact - jar` так и через `javafx application`. Что одно что другое не запускается, если запускаю файл через `cmd` выдает ошибку

> Error: Could not find or load main class sample.Main Caused by:
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Ошибку я гуглил и делал все как писали. Но никакого результата. Может это быть из-за того что я добавил `Maven` в проект через `Project - Add Framework - Maven` ?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на какой версии JDK собираете проект?

Comment: Странная структура проекта. Получается, Java-классы располагаются в `sample`? Не смотрели, где они потом в `jar`-файле? Думаю, maven (если собирать им) ожидает видеть классы в папке `main/java/<пакет>`

Comment: @zolt 8 версия.

Comment: @gooamoko но ведь при зброке указывается путь к главному классу

Comment: @ivff `maven` вполне может запихнуть классы куда-нибудь в ресурсы, если они не там, где он ожидал их увидеть. Поэтому, я бы посмотрел где они в итоге оказались. Дальше - удостоверился, что в MANIFEST.MF прописано корректное имя файла.

Comment: @gooamoko в jar файле присутствуют две папки `sample` и `MANIFES`. В первой папке содержаться все классы. В `MANIFEST`: 

`Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: sample.Main`

Comment: Файл MANIFEST.MF находится в папке META-INF?

Comment: Да, все на своих местах. Вот еще, если создать `.exe` тогда запускается. Если `.jar` - нет.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка была в том что у меня установлено `jdk 8` и `jdk 11` , `javafx` не поддерживает 11 версию. А так как у меня все `.jar` открывались только через 11, соответственно открытия файла было невозможным.